# In SPARQL, how to find whether one article belongs to a category

Tags: rdf, sparql, freebase

I am using basekb to extract some semantic information.

Following sparql query can be taken as a freebase query also (since basekb has freebase also).

Problem statement: to check whether an entity is a subcategory of a some other entity.

Eg: to check en.academy_award_for_best_supporting_actor belongs to the category en.academy_award or not.

```
prefix basekb: <http://rdf.basekb.com/ns/>
prefix public: <http://rdf.basekb.com/public/>
prefix fbase: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?aa_ct ?bb {
?aa_ct public:knownAs basekb:en.academy_awards .
?bb public:knownAs basekb:en.academy_award_for_best_supporting_actor .
**?bb rdfs:categoryOf ?aa .**
}
```

We need to change the text in bold with appropriate syntax (which i am not aware of).

Answer (score 1):

If your SPARQL implementation supports the 1.1 standard you should be able to use property paths for this assuming that the data has a strict category hierarchy e.g.

```
?bb rdfs:categoryOf+ ?aa .
```

Property paths gives a simple regex style syntax which can be used against known predicates to say that you want to match where there is a connection between `?bb` and `?aa`.

In this case the `rdfs:categoryOf+` means we require the values for `?bb` to be linked to `?aa` by a sequence of one or more `rdfs:categoryOf` links.

### Edit

You can achieve an affect akin to property paths using `UNION` for fixed length simple paths e.g.

```
{ ?bb rdfs:categoryOf ?aa }
UNION
{ ?bb rdfs:categoryOf [ rdfs:categoryOf ?aa ] }
UNION
{ ?bb rdfs:categoryOf [ rdfs:categoryOf [ rdfs:categoryOf ?aa ] ] }
```

This will match things where `?bb` is a sub-category of `?aa` in 1-3 steps, you can expand this as much as necessary up to path length you expect.  Performance will likely be poor compared to an implementation that supports property paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

It shows the following error

37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 10: syntax error at '?aa_ct' before '.'


As per the virtuoso 6.1.6, they say sparql 1.1 is partially supported.

http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/#2012-08-02:%20New%20VOS%206.1.6%20Release

Comment: Then it is likely that they don't currently support this feature

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result in the existing sparql?

Comment: @nizam.sp See my edit, it is possible with `UNION` just very verbose and limited to paths of known lengths